# How to solve $y''+4y=\cos^3(x)$ using undetermined coefficient method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + 4y = \cos^3(x)$

I know $\cos^2(x) = (\cos(2x) + 1)/2$ so...

$\cos^3(x) = (\cos(x)(\cos(2x)+1))/2$ ??

I am unsure of what I should do next to solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: $\cos^3 x=\frac{1}{4}(\cos 3x +3 \cos x)$. So your guess for a particular solution should involve $\cos x$ and $\cos 3x$ and their derivatives. Say something like $y_p=A\cos x + B \sin x + C \cos 3x + D \sin 3x$.

Comment: Use next the trigonometric identity $$2\cos(x)\cos(2x)=\cos(3x)+\cos(x).$$ Or from the start $$\cos^3(x)=\frac18(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})=\frac18(e^{3ix}+3e^{ix}+3e^{-ix}+e^{-3ix})=...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\cos 3x = 4\cos^3 x -3\cos x$ to rewrite the given equation as

$y'' + 4y = \cos^3(x) = \frac{1}{4} \cos 3x + \frac{3}{4} \cos x$

In general, the particular solution $y_P(x)$ has the following form:

$a\cos 3x + b \cos x + c\sin 3x + d\sin x$

However, here the coefficient of $y'$ is $0$ and finally you will find $c = d = 0$ even if you assume the above general form. Let's make life easier by assuming

$y_P(x) = a\cos 3x + b \cos x \implies y''_P(x) = -9a \cos 3x - b \cos x$

Hence $y_P'' + 4y_P = -5a \cos 3x + 3b \cos x = \frac{1}{4} \cos 3x + \frac{3}{4} \cos x$

Comparing the coefficients,

$a = -\frac{1}{20}$ and $b = \frac{1}{4}$

Finally

$\displaystyle y_P(x) = -\frac{1}{20} \cos 3x + \frac{1}{4} \cos x$

Answer (score 1):

In general, $\cos(mx)=a_m\cos^m(x)+a_{m-1}\cos^{m-2}(x)+\dots$ (see [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind)). In your case, we use

$$\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$$

and hence $\displaystyle\cos^3(x)=\frac{\cos(3x)+3\cos(x)}4$, which will allow you to to solve the problem using the form $y_p=A\cos(x)+B\cos(3x)$ (note that no $\sin$ terms are needed since there is no $y'$ in the equation).

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneous solution is $$A\cos 2x + B\sin 2x $$ and since $$\cos^3 x = (\cos 3x +3\cos x )/4$$ the particular solution using the method of undetermined coefficient is $$C\cos x +D\sin x +E\cos 3x +F\sin 3x$$

For the particular solution you may also use  variation of constant method $$y_p= u_1 cos2x +u_2 \sin 2x$$ where you solve for functions $u_1$ and $u_2$

Comment: This doesn't even mention where your particular solution came from...

Comment: $\cos^3 x = (\cos 3x +3\cos x )/4$

Comment: Thanks. $\ddot\smile$